# Запретить ввод основания натурального логарифма

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Как запретить ввод в input символ **`e`**? Пробовал `ng-pattern`, не помогло.

```
<input ng-model="from" type="number">
```

Comment: `e` это допустимый символ для числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что получилось. Навешиваем на событие `onkeypress` функцию, внутри которой будем смотреть, нажат ли символ **`e`**. Если нажат - отменим действия браузера по умолчанию. Для отмены действия браузера существует стандартный метод: [`preventDefault`](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action).

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  var ctrl = e.ctrlKey ? e.ctrlKey : ((key === 17) ? true : false);
  if ((key == 86 || key == 118) && ctrl) { // запрет ctrl+v
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);

document.addEventListener('contextmenu',
  e => e.preventDefault()); // запрет правой клавиши и вставить

function disableCharacterE(e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key == 69 || key == 101) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeypress="disableCharacterE(event);">
```

1. `keyCode = 69, 101` - большая буква **`E`** и маленькая буква **`e`**
2. `keyCode = 86, 118` - большая буква **`V`** и маленькая буква **`v`** (для `ctrl+v`)

Comment: в вопросе речь идет об angular, поэтому этот ответ не совсем подходит в текущем виде

Comment: @Grundy, в вопросе есть метка `javascript`, поэтому, я считаю, что подходит

Comment: а еще там есть метка angularjs :-) и лучше пользоваться возможностями фреймворка

Comment: @Grundy, вот я и основываясь на метке выбрал решение через `JS` :) если будет предложено решение через `angularjs` - так это вообще здорово, два ответа, причем через разные подходы :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov Спасибо, работает, смысл я уловил и переделал под ангуляр с использование ng-keypress.

Comment: Копируем **e** из блокнота и вставляем с помощью мыши — и событие `keypress` не срабатывает!

Comment: @DenisBubnov, вставка это стандартный способ _ввода_.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, клик по полю правой кнопкой и в контекстном меню "вставить" )

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, дополнил, пробуйте )

Comment: @DenisBubno, а еще в [X](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) можно вставлять, кликнув на колесике )

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, этого уже не сделаю, так как не располагаю *X Window System*